# Can you use Oscilloscope probes for a Function Generator?

Tags: oscilloscope, function-generator

I just bought a cheap function generator and have no test leads for it. I do have 2 pairs of oscilloscope probes with a 1X-10X switch on them. I am curious to know if I will get the same results with them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as they're set to 1x, Sure!

You will get some interesting attenuation when set to 10X, and perhaps some interesting signal distortion.

I use probes set to 1X on a signal generator pretty regularly.

Answer (score 6):

You can use it in 1x mode, but I wouldn't recommend depending on that.

Oscilloscope probes are expensive, and function generator leads are cheap.  Get a set of leads, a BNC-binding post/banana plug adaptor, or just build some leads out of a BNC jack and some wire, and you'll be fine for the lower speeds that a cheap function generator can reach.

Besides, you're likely to want both oscilloscope probes and your function generator to be operational at the same time someday.